# Convert a rhino model into XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blender, rhino

I am building a software for a client to perform scientific calculations on a 3D model provided by the client.

The client uses Rhino. I plan to build my application in WPF/c# for various reasons.

I need to import the rhino model (.3dm file) into my WPF application. I don't need a lot of 3D functions, but I would like to be able to :

- display a wireframe view of the imported model ;
- convert the mesh into my own format.

I don't need to import a lot of models. Really not, it will be something like one model every few years, so the process can be tedious, i don't care as long as it's precise and error free.

As for now, i have found a few ways to do this :

- use Rhino to [export the 3dm model in XAML format](http://docs.mcneel.com/rhino/5/help/en-us/fileio/xaml_xaml_export.htm) ;
- use Blender to import the 3dm model then export it in XAML ;
- build my own import function...

The first solution is not ideal, as i would depend on my client. Moreover, I can't test the solution without buying rhino, to finalize my offer.

I spent only a few hours on the second solution but i wasn't able to setup [jesterking's plugin](https://github.com/jesterKing/import_3dm) to import rhino files in blender. It seems to be the best solution for me though.

The third solution isn't efficient for an import function that will be scarcely used.

Any comment or suggestion are welcome (as always), because i may have missed something important here.

Also, if someone has a license for Rhino and could give me an exemple of any model converted to XAML, that would be great.

Comment: Rhino has a 90 day trial.

Comment: how did i miss that... thanks. I will install / test / amend or close my question